# Sync to all CLs within a certain Date/Time range

Tags: c#, perforce

My documentation and Google-fu is seriously failing me on this one, so:

how do I use P4API's GetChangelist() function to sync a range of files (i.e. all files from @now to @twoDaysAgo)? I can easily construct the command line to do this like so:

```
p4 changes -s submitted //...@2016/12/01,2016/12/06
```

but the API wants me to interface with the server via

```
GetChangelist(Options options, FileSpec[] files)
```

It's driving me crazy that I have to construct a combo of Options and Filespecs[] to make the request instead, and (AFAIK) can't just pass the actual command line string. Especially because all documentation seems to be non-existent.

Can somebody enlighten me as to what kind of filespec parameters I have to pass along? (I think that's what I need to use to specify the fact that I want to get a range of all CLs inside a certain time?) Thanks!

(As an aside: I was surprised there isn't a "P4API" tag yet, and I can't create one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after a couple more hours of digging, I have found that there *is* a way to feed the actual command line parameters to the command. You create a DepotSpec, and then something like this is working for me to restrict the time range for CLs retrieved from the server:

```
ChangesCmdOptions changeListOptions = new ChangesCmdOptions(ChangesCmdFlags.FullDescription|ChangesCmdFlags.IncludeTime, null, 0, ChangeListStatus.None, null);
FileSpec[] fileSpecs = new FileSpec[1] { new FileSpec(new DepotPath("//depot/...@2016/12/05 21:57:30,@now"), null, null, null) };                       
IList<Changelist> changes = m_Repository.GetChangelists(changeListOptions, fileSpecs);
```

All this might be "indulgent smile" old news to people who've worked with the API for a while. It's just all a bit confusing to newcomers when documentation like the two pages mentioned in this post ("FileSpec object docs", "SyncFiles method docs") are offline now: [Perforce Api - How to command "get revision [changelist number]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374994/perforce-api-how-to-command-get-revision-changelist-number)

Comment: Not gonna mark this as a correct answer yet. Would love some input from people who really know the API.

Comment: This method works best because you don't get any bugs with the time range. Use the other method if you want a cleaner approach and don't care about the timestamp (date range only).

Answer (score 0):

And here's the non-command line version that you really want to use, from the Perforce documentation (once you find it :))

```
PathSpec path = new DepotPath("//depot/...");
DateTimeVersion lowerTimeStamp = new DateTimeVersion(new DateTime(2016,12,06));
DateTimeVersion upperTimeStamp = new DateTimeVersion(DateTime.Now);
VersionSpec version = new VersionRange(lowerTimeStamp, upperTimeStamp);
FileSpec[] fileSpecs = { new FileSpec(path, version) };

ChangesCmdOptions changeListOptions = new ChangesCmdOptions(ChangesCmdFlags.FullDescription | ChangesCmdFlags.IncludeTime, null, 0, ChangeListStatus.None, null);
IList<Changelist> changes = m_Repository.GetChangelists(changeListOptions, fileSpecs);
```

Comment: This is the officially correct way, BUT - I couldn't get it to work for the time stamps. The returned list contains all CLs within the specified *date* range, but the timestamps are ignored.